# What are the limits of series acceleration?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-acceleration

There are many questions on series acceleration already on this site, my question is on the limits of these type of approaches as a whole.  Can I, by iteratively using acceleration techniques, make a series that converges as quickly as I want?

If so, is there any limit to this approach? For example, perhaps one could make the convergence arbitrarily fast, but not change the rate in an asymptotic sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Philosophically speaking (ha-ha) there is no limit to acceleration. However, without precise restrictions on the method of acceleration, the philosophical answer would be practically useless.

And, when you define your method then -- of course -- the limitations will occur.

Nevertheless, Euler and others would successfully accelerate series. And they would iterate their method to ultimately reach another efficiency level. The crucial moment is about catching a pattern during the consecutive passage from the given stage-series to the next one. Thus, by infinite iteration of simple series like the ones for $\ \log 2\ $ or $\ \frac\pi 4\ $ or $\ \frac{\pi^2} 6,\ $ they were obtaining series converging almost as fast as standard Taylor series.

Comment: Do you have any favorite references for these acceleration techniques?

Comment: I am not well-read. Konrad Knop, in his classic, goes further than other textbooks (I've seen some many years ago) while some other texts provide sharper examples but without infinite iteration. Of the texts at which I had glanced in the past, the sharpest seems by Wacław Sierpiński, "Infinite operations". It has several pages devoted to the series acceleration. (I did some such infinite iterations for fun, a few examples; I can force myself to do it again if people were interested -- perhaps most everybody can).